# How can I chain having() clause on my eloquent request

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-livewire

I have to make a request to filter some datas on my laravel app (v8).
I'm using livewire to filtering datas on a table.

The full request :

```php
    $datas = Client::withSum(
            [ 'statistics_products as statistics_products_sum_'.$this->n_1 => fn ($query) => $query->where('yr', $this->n_1)],
    'total_ht')
        ->withSum(
            [ 'statistics_products as statistics_products_sum_'.$this->n_2 => fn ($query) => $query->where('yr', $this->n_2)],
    'total_ht')
        ->withSum(
            [ 'statistics_products as statistics_products_sum_'.$this->n => fn ($query) => $query->where('yr', $this->n)],
    'total_ht')

        // For is_deleted selection
        ->when($this->deleted, function ($query, $deleted) {
            if($deleted == 'oui') {
                $query->where('is_delete', 1);
            } elseif($deleted === 'non') {
                $query->where('is_delete', 0);
            }
        })
        // For dpt selection
        ->when($this->dpt, function ($query, $dpt) {
            $query->where('postal_code', 'LIKE', $this->dpt. '%');
        })
        // For referent selection
        ->when($this->referent, function ($query, $referent) {
            if($referent === 'oui') {
                $query->whereColumn('client_num', 'sign_num');
            } elseif($referent === 'non') {
                $query->whereColumn('client_num', '!=', 'sign_num');
            }
        })
        ->when($this->ca, function ($query, $ca) {

            if($this->year != null) {
                
                if($ca === 'A') {
                    $query->having('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '<', 20000)->orHaving('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '=', null);
                }elseif($ca === 'B') {
                    $query->havingBetween('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, [20001, 40000]);
                }elseif($ca === 'C') {
                    $query->havingBetween('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, [40001, 60000]);
                }elseif($ca === 'D') {
                    $query->havingBetween('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, [60001, 100000]);
                }elseif($ca === 'E') {
                    $query->havingBetween('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, [100001, 500000]);
                }elseif($ca === 'F') {
                    $query->having('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '>', 500000);
                }    
            }
        })
            // For search
            ->when($this->search, function ($query, $search) {
                $query->searchIn3Columns('society_name', 'city','postal_code', $search);
            })
        
            ->paginate($this->pagination_number);
```

But this part doesn't work properly :

```php
if($ca === 'A') {
            $query->having('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '<', 20000)
                  ->orHaving('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '=', null);
                }
```

Here I only get results for 'statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '<', 20000

I don't get the result where it's null...

Do you know how can I chain two having clause?

Answer (score 0):

This part of the query doesn't seem right:

```
->orHaving('statistics_products_sum_'.$this->year, '=', null); // = null ???
```

Maybe try with:

```
if ($ca === 'A') {
   $query->having('statistics_products_sum_' . $this->year, '<', 20000)
         ->orWhereNull('statistics_products_sum_' . $this->year);
}
```